# CMake - how should I remove duplicates in a space-separated list?

Tags: list, cmake, duplicates

'Proper' CMake lists allow for

```
list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES my_list_name)
```

but this won't work with a "list" which is just a space-separated string, such as `CMAKE_C_FLAGS`. What's the best/simplest way to avoid duplicates in this kind of lists?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isn't really a way to do this that doesn't require changing your string to a list first.

Use [`separate_arguments`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/separate_arguments.html) to do that:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

set(ARGS "foo baz bawk bawk bawk")
message(STATUS "args: ${ARGS}")
# args: foo baz bawk bawk bawk

set(ARG_LIST ${ARGS})
separate_arguments(ARG_LIST)
message(STATUS "arg list: ${ARG_LIST}")
# arg list: foo;baz;bawk;bawk;bawk

list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES ARG_LIST)
message(STATUS "arg list: ${ARG_LIST}")
# arg list: foo;baz;bawk

# little utility function to join the list back into a string
function(JOIN VALUES GLUE OUTPUT)
  string (REGEX REPLACE "([^\\]|^);" "\\1${GLUE}" _TMP_STR "${VALUES}")
  string (REGEX REPLACE "[\\](.)" "\\1" _TMP_STR "${_TMP_STR}") #fixes escaping
  set (${OUTPUT} "${_TMP_STR}" PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()

JOIN("${ARG_LIST}" " " ARGS)
message(STATUS "args: ${ARGS}")
# args: foo baz bawk
```

Want a function? Ok:

```
function(REMOVE_DUPES ARG_STR OUTPUT)
  set(ARG_LIST ${ARG_STR})
  separate_arguments(ARG_LIST)
  list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES ARG_LIST)
  string (REGEX REPLACE "([^\\]|^);" "\\1 " _TMP_STR "${ARG_LIST}")
  string (REGEX REPLACE "[\\](.)" "\\1" _TMP_STR "${_TMP_STR}") #fixes escaping
  set (${OUTPUT} "${_TMP_STR}" PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()

set(ARGS "foo baz bawk bawk bawk fiz")
message(STATUS "args: ${ARGS}")
REMOVE_DUPES(ARGS DEDUPLICATED)
message(STATUS "args: ${DEDUPLICATED}")
```

Comment: You have a mistake in function. Renamed ARGS to ARG_STR but not in the function body.

Comment: Also this might break the compilation of the project in case in the ARG_STR there is an escaped string like '\"/home/user_a/\"".